# Rename "Create Issue" to "Create..." in Jira

Tags: customization, jira, jira-ondemand

Is it possible to rename the word "Issue" to something less associated with "Defect"/"Problem"? In Jira Agile I'd like to  be tracking Work and vision and stories and all kinds of other items with a positive connotation!

I understand that Jira's underlying name for everything is "Issue" just like it is "Work Item" for TFS, but I don't want that term to show up everywhere.

I'd prefer it to show the right "term" dependign on the situation, or just show a simple "Create..." which is completely neutral.   On the Task board it would make sense to have "Create Task", on the Product backlog I'd expect "Create Story" or "Create Epic".

Just to be clear, we're targeting Jira OnDemand, not the on-premise version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can get this done by using InProduct translation plugin for JIRA.

This plugin is available in marketplace:

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.translations.jira.inproduct

Comment: No matter, valuable link for other people who are more lucky than I am :).

Comment: Put the question out to Atlassian Directly and there is no way to do this for OnDemand for the moment.